# Add text field in multipleTextBox

Tags: javascript, html

how can i, load a file and make it to an option ?

so if we say i have a file on an sever, or my desktop.

how can i make a function that can handle that¨?

maybe with AJAX?

```
        <input type="text" name="name" value="text " />
    </form>

    <br>

    <button onclick="myRemove()">Remove Option </button>

    <button type="button" onclick="myCreate()">Create Option</button>

    <script>
        function myRemove() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
            x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
        }

        function myCreate()
{
    var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
    y.add(option);
```

Comment: how can i, load a file and make it to an option ?

and a file from an sever ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment:

```
document.getElementsByName("name");
```

returns array of elements. You have to extract what you want.

You have to change to something like this:

```
function myCreate()
{
    var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
    y.add(option);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an input tag to fetch your own value

```
<form >
    <select id="mySelect" size="30" multiple>
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Pear</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="myValue"/>
    <input type="Submit" name="name" value="Submit " />
</form>
```

Then in your oncreate method

```
function myCreate(){
var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var option = document.createElement("option");
var x = document.getElementById('myValue').value
option.text = x;
y.add(option);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my code

```
</head>
<body>
<form >
        <select id="mySelect" size="30" multiple>
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Pear</option>
            <option>Banana</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
        </select>

        <input type="Submit" name="name" value="Submit " />
    </form>



    <br>

    <button onclick="myRemove()">Remove Option </button>
<input id="add" type="text"> 
    <button type="button" onclick="myCreate()">Create Option</button>

    <script>
        function myRemove() {
           $('#mySelect').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
        }

        function myCreate()
        {
        var value = $("#add").val();
        $("#mySelect").append('<option value='+value+'>'+value+'</option>');            


        }


    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```